# How to avoid to add duplicate string in append string connector logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have following json array input -

```
"results": [
  { "tableName" : "ABC","id":"11"},
  { "tableName" : "ZX","id":"11"},
  { "tableName" : "ABC","id":"11"}
]}
```

In logic app i have used `` in `For_each` I'm able to append string successfuly but how to avoid adding already present string ? like above example my current output is -
`ABC,ZX,ABC`
i want - `ABC,ZX`
[image]

Comment: it works for me thanks for your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the Array to implement, there is a [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#union) function to return a collection that has all the items from the specified collections. It will return a collection without duplicate string. Then use `join` action to return the string.

[image]

Cause the `union` function must contain two collection at least, so I used two same collections. The expression is like this: `union(variables('tablename'),variables('tablename'))`

The below is the result.

[image]

[image]

Hope this could help you.

Comment: very very nice solution!!